# Why my AnimationSet doesn't execute properly?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

**Problem**

When I try to animate my TextView using this zoom-out-then-zoom-in animation, it doesn't scale properly.
My TextView will be instantly scaled to like 50% of it's size, then, right after that, the animation will start to play and when it will finish the size of TextView will be about 50% of its initial size, and right after that it will return to 100%.

This is the animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Zoom Out -->
    <scale
        android:duration="750"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.6"
        android:toYScale="0.6">
    </scale>

    <!-- Zoom In -->
    <scale
        android:duration="750"
        android:startOffset="750"
        android:fromXScale="0.6"
        android:fromYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1">
    </scale>
</set>
```

---

**What I tried**

I tried to look into the documentation for SetAnimation and ScaleAnimation but didn't found anything useful to solve my problem.

I tried changing some values and I'm gonna describe here how it did affect the animation.
I will talk of sizes like 2.0 and 0.6, not of couples, because I've always set fromXScale  equals to fromYScale and toXScale equals to toYScale in my experiments. So,

If I go from 2.0 to 0.6, then from 0.6 to 2.0, the animation is executed correctly (it will start from the actual size of the text view no 2x, and it will return to the actual size)
If I go from 2.0 to 1.0, then from 1.0 to 2.0, the animation will start from 2.0.. go to 1.0 and return to 2.0.. And immediately after that, the TextView will return to its original size.

**EDIT**

I just tryied another thing. I did the opposite of the animation below, a zoom-in-then-zoom-out animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Zoom In -->
    <scale
        android:duration="750"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5">
    </scale>

    <!-- Zoom Out -->
    <scale
        android:duration="750"
        android:startOffset="750"
        android:fromXScale="1.5"
        android:fromYScale="1.5"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0">
    </scale>
</set>
```

And the behavior perpetrated, only this time at reverse: The view instantly *zooms in* the the animation executes and them instantly *zooms out* to the original state.

---

**Question**

How can I execute the animation properly, with values `fromXScale=1.0 --> toXScale=0.6 --> toXScale=1.0` and `fromYScale=1.0 --> toYScale=0.6 --> toYScale=1` ?

Why my code is not working?

Comment: use one scale animation plus custom interpolator that starts at 0 has value of 1 in rhe middle and ends with 0 at the end (some form of sin function)

Comment: Can you show me something else? I know interpolators are used to modify the speed at which an animation is executed. Are you implying that they can also reverse the view?

Comment: sute, try the interpolator like sine wave

Comment: I don't know how to define an interpolator and  I want to understand why my code doesn't work, not just try a workaround. The reason is I just tried another animation and all seems to have this behavior

Comment: this is not any workaround, sets are very hard to combine smooth anims of the same type

Comment: and finally you end up with a custom interpolator, you will see

Comment: Fine, but for what I know, one can only set constants as interpolators, not functions. I mean, the interpolator is the one responseble for the change in speed of the animation, but it doesn't change itself. Could you show me how to do that via code?

Comment: exttend Interpolator and set its instance via Animation.setInterpolator